# how to open other links in browser not in webview?

Tags: android, webview

hello i have a webview android app. i want that my website open in webview only and if somone click on a url that is not related to my website then open in browser. Example: if my website is little.com and if some one clcik  a link that is facebook.com or google.com then facebbok or google open in browser.

**androidmainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.little.example">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- The below is for the splash screen and we need no action bar and the default theme -->
        <activity android:name=".homeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**mainactivity.kt**

```
    package com.little.example
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.Handler
    import android.webkit.WebBackForwardList
    import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
    import android.webkit.WebView
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient
    import com.little.example.R
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    import androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity
    import androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.ExtraData
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
    import android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T




    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            webview.loadUrl("https://little.com")
             webview.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()



    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()){
            webview.goBack()
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    private inner class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            if (!url.contains("little.com")) {//for example
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                startActivity(intent)
                return true
            }

            view.loadUrl(url)
            return false

        }}

}
```

Comment: Is that all links are present on your application screen?

Comment: yes my website have links, i want my links open in  webview like little.com or little.com/profile.php or little.com/settting.php  BUT IF any one click on a link that is not related to my website  then open in browser like facebook.com or any other url @VishalBari

Comment: In that case, you need to make a list of website which you want to open in your webview. So you need to check whether the link which is pressed by a user is present in your list or not if it is present then show in your  webview else show in browser.

Comment: Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(other link than your list));
startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: if i make other links open in new window tab in my website code and in webview is there any way for open new window links in browser not in webview @VishalBari

Comment: Use custom _WebViewClient_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can handle every url as you wish just set up your webview via customized WebViewClient

```
mWebView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()

}

private inner class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        if (!url.contains("little.com")) {//for example
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
            startActivity(intent)
            return true
        }

        mWebView.loadUrl(url)
        return false
```

Comment: i have no idea how to implement this code>>> @kirquduck

Comment: @NishaAtram i've changed my answer

Comment: just white screen @kirguduck

Comment: i  have updated in question please check @kirquduck

Comment: @NishaAtram try to change true and false. i am not in front of comp, sorry. stackoverflaw it's just a direction. if you want next time resolve same issue by yourself you should try to deep and understand. it is not just free help for beginners

Comment: thank you @kirquduck code is correct problem in url script working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

you can use this code to open a page in a browser

Answer (score -1):

By using custom tabs in androidx

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
            CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: OP specifically asked to open link in browser. This will open in webview.